# Android Recycler View - reverse layout inside Constraint Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `ConstraintLayout` which is constrained at the top to the `parent` and at the bottom by an `EditText`.  This works fine, however as soon as I set the recycler to **`reverseLayout=true`** the first item at the bottom has to be scrolled down to be fully seen if I have more items than the screen can display.  The preview is exactly how it happens on a real device making me think I am missing something out of the layout.

**NOTE:**

If I remove the bottom constraint to the `EditText` in the `RecyclerView` from `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/feedMessageInput"` to`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` then this problem does not happen, however this is not desirable.

Xml Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_half"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:background="@drawable/shp_rounded_rectangle_transparent_white_05"
    tools:context=".ui.messages.feed.FeedFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/feedEmptyImageView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size_xxxxxlarge"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_xxxxxlarge"
        android:contentDescription="@string/no_recipients_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_messages_124dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/feedRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_triple"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_half"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/feedMessageInput"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:reverseLayout="true"
        tools:itemCount="5"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row_message" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/feedRecipient"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size_medium"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_medium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_normal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/feedMessageInput"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/feedMessageInputView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/feedMessageInputView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/feedMessageInputView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shp_rounded_rectangle_transparent_white_10"
        android:maxHeight="@dimen/message_background_input_max_height"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/feedMessageInput"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/feedMessageInput"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/feedMessageInput"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/feedMessageInput" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/feedMessageInput"
        style="@style/MessagingEditText.NoUnderline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLength="@integer/max_message_length"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_half"
        android:textSize="@dimen/message_input_text_size"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/feedSelectTemplate"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="@dimen/message_background_input_max_height"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="@dimen/message_background_input_height"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/feedRecipient"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/feedRecycler"
        tools:hint="Send message to +447445343433"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/feedSendMessage"
        style="@style/MessagingFloatingActionButton.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_sms_message_send_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/feedSelectTemplate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/feedMessageInput" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/feedSelectTemplate"
        style="@style/MessagingFloatingActionButton.Small.Contrast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_sms_message_template_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/feedSendMessage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/feedMessageInput"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/feedMessageInput" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Current Incorrect preview when multiple rows that scroll off the top and bottom - which is incorrect :**

[image: image with multiple rows]

**How I expect `reverseLayout=true` to work no matter how many rows scroll off the top:**

[image: how I'd like it to look always no matter how many items]

Any help with something I may have missed would be appreciated.

Comment: Try changing the width of your _RecyclerView_ from match_parent to `0dp` (match_constraints). That my work for you.

Comment: @Cheticamp Hi thanks for your comment.  I can confirm that this does indeed work!  If you can write as an answer (and if possible your rationale why this works) I'll accept as an answer.  I still don't understand the requirement for the width change from `0dp` over `match_parent` and how that affects the height, and why this is only required for reverse layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) for *ConstraintLayout*:

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".

Why does this sort of work? My guess is that it is not really supported but has not been disabled and is probably not tested. The short answer is to use `match_constraints` (`0dp`) exclusively and to avoid `match_parent` at all times when it comes to *ConstraintLayout*.

Answer (score -1):

Faced with the same issue. It looks like ConstraintLayout issue (still is in beta).
I've rewritten xml layout to use LinearLayout and it works for me.
But still waiting for the fix from Google.